# Button not firing event on ASP.NET control Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, button

I'm creating a Button on a `ComboxChanged` Event,

```
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.ID = "btnNum1";
    btn.Text = "Edit";
    btn.Click += btnTest_Click;        
    pnl.Controls.Add(btn);
```

The event code is as followed

```
 public void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    Response.Write(btn.ID);        
    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
}
```

I have tried, both `Response.Write` and `Response.Redirect`. None of them, works.
Same page gets refreshed. Does any one has any idea.

Button has to be created Dynamically, hence I can't try the `Page_Init`

I have also tried the CommandArgument event that also didn't work.
Any idea.

Comment: Does it even hit the Button Click Event?

Comment: I guess thats not happening. But don't know why based on the code. It seems right.

Comment: Are you recreating the button on each postback?

Comment: The creation part is in, comboBox Change event. So i don't have an idea. Either its getting created again or not?

Comment: Does the button disappear on the page after you clicked it? If yes, it is not getting recreated. That should be done for the Click event to work.

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Yes it is getting disappeared. But its on combo box event. Any idea how to re-create? that event?

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Yes I recreated the button events, It did work. Please post it as your answer. So That i can accept it. Thank You

Comment: freefaller has already posted an acceptable answer, I'ld go with that.

Comment: Sorry @Mt.Schneiders, I didn't mean to steal your thunder

Answer (score 4):

As Mt. Schneiders has mentioned in his comments under your question - if you dynamically add a control to a page, you **must** re-add it on the post-back.  Just because you've added it as part of the event handler, does not mean that ASP.NET automatically creates the control on the post-back.

You need to store in the page the fact that the control was created - my personal preference would be to put the code in it's own function and set a `ViewState` value...

```
private void CreateButton()
{
  Button btn = new Button();
  btn.ID = "btnNum1";
  btn.Text = "Edit";
  btn.Click += btnTest_Click;        
  pnl.Controls.Add(btn);
  ViewState["buttonAdded"] = true;
}
```

And call the function from your `ComboxChanged` event.

Then, on the `Page_Load`, you need to check to see if the button was added previously...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(Page.IsPostBack && ViewState["buttonAdded"] != null)
  {
    CreateButton()
  }
}
```

(Note, I've stated `Page_Load` rather than `Page_Init` because the `ViewState` is not created at the `Page_Init` stage of the [ASP.NET page life cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/LIBRARY/ms178472.ASPX))

Answer (score 0):

when u added ur dynamic event handler it will store in particular control view state so when the page post back happened it will lose that event handler so u can implement load view state method which will come with page events code should be like

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I still can't see anything happening. Same effect.??

Answer (score 0):

Try this `btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnTest_Click);`.

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.ID = "btnNum1";
btn.Text = "Edit";
btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnTest_Click);     
pnl.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Comment: Noting. Pages gets refresh, Neither Response.write nor Redirect

Answer (score 0):

Assume this is the code that create the button :

```
 If ddl.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        Dim b As New Button
        b.ID = "mybutton"
        b.Text = "i'm a button"
        panel.Controls.Add(b)
        AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Button_Click

    End If
```

Note the AddHandler ok it is exactly what you're looking for then

```
  Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim b As Button = CType(sender, Button)
    Dim l As Label = CType(Me.FindControl("testlabel"), Label)
    l.Text = b.Text & " my id is " & b.ID.ToString

End Sub
```

that's all :)

Comment: Your code looks more like my code, but in VB.net. Can you do it in C#. Sorry for too much to ask